# How to simplify this code using generic types?

Tags: c#, generics

```
private delegate T MyFunc<T>(int i);

private static double SumNumber(int i, int n, MyFunc<double> func)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = i; i <= n; j++)
    {
        sum += func(j);
    }
    return sum;
}

private static Vector SumVector(int i, int n, MyFunc<Vector> func)
{
    Vector sum = new Vector(0.0, 0.0);
    for (int j = i; i <= n; j++)
    {
        sum += func(j);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is a program to calculate sum of MyFunc(j) where j is i to n.

I tried to use interface like:

```
interface IAddable<T>
{
    static T operator +(T x, T y);
}
```

but it didn't work.

So what should I do?

Comment: you could use Func instead of MyFunc this way you would not have to create a delegate and use the one that is in .net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, note that in many ways the non-generic overload version is simpler. Generics do not support operators, nor do interfaces.

Indeed, if there *are* `Sum` methods available for your types (perhaps via extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>`) the caller could use simply:

```
var data = sourceData.Select(projection).Sum();
```

where `projection` is the moral equivalent of `func`.

For doing it *your* way, what you might try first is `dynamic`:

```
private static T Sum<T>(int i, int n, Func<int,T> func)
{
    if(i >= n) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    T sum = func(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; i <= n; j++)
    {
        sum = (dynamic)sum + (dynamic)func(j);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

otherwise, there are some tricks you can do to fake generic operators (see [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html)), or you could *pass in* the accumulator method (i.e. `Func<T,T,T> add`) as a parameter.

Comment: @Jon beat me looking up the MiscUtil link ;p

Comment: Can an object of `dynamic` type be implicitly converted into object of type `T`? I mean, should you not write this instead : `sum = (T)((dynamic)sum + (dynamic)func(j));`

Comment: @Nawaz `dynamic` can be implicitly converted to *anything*, but note that the check is at runtime; there's a big assumption in there: that ***there exists*** a defined operator `+(T,T)`, which returns `T`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I was about to post a fairly similar answer, so I happened to have it ready :)

Comment: @Nawaz your `(T)` addition makes sense too, and arguably makes the intent clearer; the *result* is the same, and I certainly wouldn't be *opposed* to having the extra `(T)` there.

Comment: Is `dynamic` recommended here? What are the typical cases where you need to bypass the static type checking and use dynamic?

Comment: @Hemal simply: there is no direct language mechanism for supporting operators against generics. So you *have* to go a little outside the box. `dynamic` is convenient, but I'd *probably* lean towards either the MiscUtil approach or the "accumulator function" approach if I was using this in heavy-hitting work.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I didn't know about dynamic earlier but after checking I felt static checking need not be sacrificed here.

Comment: Damn Marc, your awesome. How can i not think this much :(. I should learn generics alot now. Good solution though.